# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type found

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, autowired, spring-annotations

I am making a Spring + Hibernate + Maven project. After basic login, I tried to use annotations, but got stuck there. I have tried everything possible, still can't get rid of this error **NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type found for dependency**

Here's the configuration:

Controller

```
package com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/ProceedWithLogin")
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
AdminService adminService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/uthja", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doLogin(@RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    String message = "";
    if (adminService.doAuthenticate(name, password)) {
        // Authentication successful
        message = "Welcome!!";
    } else {
        // Authentication failed
        message = "Not Welcome!!";
    }
    return new ModelAndView("results", "message", message);

}}
```

Service:

```
package com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan.service;

public interface AdminService {

boolean doAuthenticate(String name, String password);
}
```

ServiceImplementation

```
package com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan.serviceimpl;

@Service("AdminServiceImpl")
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService {

@Override
public boolean doAuthenticate(String name, String password) {
    return true;
}}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>theFloorPlan</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 </servlet-class>
 <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
        WEB-INF/theFloorPlan-servlet.xml
        WEB-INF/spring-conf/spring.xml
 </param-value>
 </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>theFloorPlan</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 <listener>
     <listener-class>
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

spring.xml(Truncated version)

```
   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <context:annotation-config />
   <context:component-scan base-    package="com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan.service" />
```

Here's the error that I get

```
2015-09-15 13:00:06,575 [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan.service.AdminService com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan.controller.LoginController.adminService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan.service.AdminService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor287.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:362)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I remove the @Autowired annotation from the Controller code, it works fine, so it means the problem is down to the annotation. From what I think, the package where the service code is kept is not being scanned by the spring container, but for the life of it, I can't understand why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change from `@Service("AdminServiceImpl")
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService` to    `@Service("adminService")
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService`

Comment: tried, but the error still persists.

Comment: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan.serviceimpl" />` is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the implementation of the service is in the package `com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan.serviceimpl`, you have to add that package to the component scan. So add `<context:component-scan base-package="com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan.serviceimpl" />` in your Spring config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify   `@Service("AdminServiceImpl")`  to `@Service("adminService")`since its looking for bean with name `adminService` which is being autowired.

Answer (score 0):

All the beans to be autowired must be inside the package(s) visible during component scan, you can use annotation or context entry

```
context:component-scan base-package="com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan"/>
```

or

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.pnpjunction.thefloorplan"} )
```